# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=PendingIntent{ }

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, activitynotfoundexception

I am trying to execute another app from my app using PendingIntent. I get other apps' pending Intent value and do this (I got pending intent value in String type)

```
public class NotificationCrawlingService extends NotificationListenerService {

AppDatabase appDatabase;
WordDatabase wordDatabase;
NotificationDatabase notificationDatabase;
Context context;
PackageManager pm;
NotificationEntity ne;
AllFragment allFragment;
RecyclerViewAdapter rv;
List<NotiData> notiData;
NotificationEntity noti;
Notification notification;


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    appDatabase = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(context);
    wordDatabase = WordDatabase.getWordDatabase(context);
    notificationDatabase = NotificationDatabase.getNotificationDatabase(context);
    pm = context.getPackageManager();
    notification = sbn.getNotification();
    Bundle extras = notification.extras;
    String pakage_name = sbn.getPackageName();
    String app_name = findApp_name(pakage_name);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = notification.contentIntent;


Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pendingIntent));
        startActivity(intent1);
```

However it won't work.
Shows this error in Log

*2020-08-17 16:29:27.197 4503-4503/com.example.alimseolap1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.alimseolap1, PID: 4503
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=PendingIntent{78fb01: android.os.BinderProxy@b9c2b85} }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2018)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4689)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:234)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:791)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:933)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1185)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1173)
at com.example.alimseolap1.views.Fragment.AllFragment$2.onReceive(AllFragment.java:170)
at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:313)
at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:121)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)*

What might be the problem?

Comment: What is your pending intent string value? You should have started your post with it.

Comment: @blackapps PendingIntent{78fb01: android.os.BinderProxy@b9c2b85} is the value

Comment: Please show the code you use to build the `PendingIntent`. Edit your post and put the code in there. Don't put the code in a comment.

Comment: @DavidWasser Here, I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert a `PendingIntent` into a `Uri` like that. Instead of:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = notification.contentIntent;
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pendingIntent));
startActivity(intent1);
```

You do this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = notification.contentIntent;
pendingIntent.send();
```

This launches the `Intent` that was wrapped in the `PendingIntent`.

Comment: I get red underline on that send() method.

Comment: There's some overloading methods related to send(). Maybe they could solve the problem?

Comment: calling `send()` can throw `PendingIntent.CanceledException`, so you probably need to wrap the call in a `try/catch` block.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I have last question, if I want to store pendingintent in database to redirect user whenever user want to, how do I pass that pendingintent to databae? Only strings and integers can be saved into databases right?

Comment: You can't store a `PendingIntent` in a database. It is just a token pointing to the real thing and you can't get all the data from the real thing. `PendingIntent` is just a transient thing, you can't make it persistent.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tenqube.notisave&hl=en_US
This application redirects users to a specific activity of 3rd party apps with self stored notifications. How does this work then?